# how to create textbox dynamically after click (button)? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to figure out how to create a textbox (or other controls) dynamically, after click on button. I have written a function that does work if I add it to the `Page_Load` method, but it does not work as related to a specific button (after click).

Also, I tried to understand how to count my clicks.

`.aspx` markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="addexProductBTN" runat="server" Text="add" onclick="addexProductBTN_Click"/>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="DynamicControlsHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

`.aspx.cs` code:

```
int count = 0;
protected void addnewProductBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    addControlTB();
}

protected void addControlTB()
{
    Table tbldynamic = new Table();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TextBox NewProdTB = new TextBox();
    NewProdTB.ID = "DynamicTextBox";
    NewProdTB.Text = "";
    tc.Controls.Add(NewProdTB);
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tbldynamic.Rows.Add(tr);
    DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(tbldynamic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing has to do with viewstate:

```
TextBox NewProdTB = new TextBox();
NewProdTB.EnableViewState = false;
```

Try to play around how the behaviour changes, when set to false and true;

[THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) here is an article about the viewstate behaviour.

The "count" part of your question: if you need a global variable that survives reload of the page, you should try to use [session object](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp).